# how to add leapyear in DOB using datediff

Tags: vb.net, msdn

I'm using `datediff` to show `dateofbirth`. Can anyone help me on how and where to add `msgbox("Sorry, INVALID date of BIRTH")`?

This is my code and where the error occurs without `messagebox`.

```
 Dim i As New Integer

Private Function IsLeapYear(ByVal intYear As Integer) As Boolean
    IsLeapYear = (Month(DateSerial(i, 2, 29)) = 2)
End Function


Private Sub ComboMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboMonth.SelectedIndexChanged
    '   cboMonth.Items.Clear()

    If Me.cboMonth.Text = "February" Then
        For i = 1 To 28
            cboDay.Items.Add(i)
        Next

    ElseIf Me.cboMonth.Text = "January" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "March" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "May" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "July" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "September" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "November" Then
        For i = 1 To 31
            cboDay.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    ElseIf Me.cboMonth.Text = "April" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "June" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "August" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "October" Or Me.cboMonth.Text = "December" Then
        For i = 1 To 30
            cboDay.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub cboYear_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboYear.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dob As Date
    Dim today As Long
  dob = Me.cboMonth.Text & "-" & Me.cboDay.Text & "-" & Me.cboYear.Text 'here error says date is not valid
    today = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dob, Now) / 365
    Me.txtAge.Text = today
End Sub

Sub years()
    For i = 1950 To 2050
        cboYear.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub

Sub days()
    For i = 1 To 31
        cboDay.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `newDt = oldDt.AddYears(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, here is one way to handle the failing of a convert to date:

```
    Dim dateAsText as String = Me.cboMonth.Text & "-" & Me.cboDay.Text & "-" & Me.cboYear.Text
    If Not Date.TryParse(dateAsText, dob) Then
       'handle what to do if not converted to date
    Else
       'continue with coding...
    End If
```

On another note, you may want to look at how accurate your results are.  Doing math for days and dividing by 365 will have some inherit errors over time from leap years.  But how to calculate age is a different question, if you want to look at that...